# Hosting website on PC through firewall

Tags: web-server, firewall, modem, port-forwarding

I would like to host a website on my PC. It is connected to a firewall which in turn is connected to a DSL Modem.
Actually I am not getting the correct way to configure port forwarding.

Modem: Beetel 220BXI.
Firewall: Netgear FVS124G.

Can anyone give me any idea of port forwarding in the above setup.
I am also using a static IP configured on the modem.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the web, the Netgear's port forwarding is called "rules" on this device, so as long as you have access to the device, you should be able to setup the device.